# RecyclerView inside CollapsingToolBarLayout is not getting scrolled

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one RecyclerView inside CollapsingToolbarLayout and one outside AppBarLayout. When my collapsingLayout will expand to its maxHeight, then I want my internalRecyclerView to be scrolled, and when collapsingLayout will collapse to its minHeight then I want outsideRecyclerView to be scrolled .  I tried to enable/disable AppBarLayout.Behavoiur.DragCallback , that also not working.Below is my xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        tools:context="replace_demo.com.replacedemo.ScrollingActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:minHeight="160dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="#80ffcc00"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/internalRecyclerVw"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/outerRecyclerVw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnUpdates"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here, but I know Android Studio already comes with pre-built list of Activity layouts that may or may not have the functionality you require.